# Laravel: Getting the first item after querying a collection already?

Tags: laravel

I need access to an entire collection but I also want to pull out and use the first item on the collection.  Can `first()` be used outside the context of a query like this to get the first item?

```
$items = Item::with(['name'])->where('prod_num', '=', $num)->get();

$firstItem = $items->first();
```

Comment: ^ This is fine, `$items` will still have all items, and `$firstItem` will be the first one in the `Collection`. Did you try this code? What errors are you getting (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you call the `first()` method to get the first element in the collection.
Since you called `->get()` in `$items` it will return a collection, so you can call the `first()` method in it.

Comment: `->get()` returns a `Collection`, and `$items->first()` syntactically equivalent to `$items[0]`

Comment: Ok, i refactored my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where you query a Model using Eloquent, as you are doing, it returns a Eloquent Collection.

Eloquent Collections extend Collections (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections#method-intersect), which have `first()` method available. So, you can use it.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-first